# Scrolled event is not firing properly for angular2-infinite-scroll

Tags: angular

I am trying to use [angular2-infinite-scroll](https://github.com/orizens/angular2-infinite-scroll) as its described, currently I am using 0.2+ version, and previously I was using 0.1.95 version which was working fine, but then I upgraded it & this is causing some issues. scrolled event is not being called every time I scroll, to make it work I need to scroll back to the top and then scroll to the bottom. Since I have given `infiniteScrollDistance = 2` it should be called on half way around of the page.

Here is the code:

```ts
<table class="table table-hover inline-edit"
    infinite-scroll
    [infiniteScrollDistance]="2"
    [infiniteScrollThrottle]="400"
    (scrolled)="onScrollDown()">

// Function from component
onScrollDown() {
    this.contactService.pagination.currentPageNumber += 1;
    this.contactService.getContactList();
}
```

I have already posted this on there GitHub but no response

Comment: Please post the code that demonstrates what you try to accomplish and what you tried.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer edited my question, I am using angular2-infinte-scroll lib

Comment: I assume you did add the `InfiniteScrollModule` to `imports` of the module where you use above code? Otherwise it looks fine to me (don't know the `InfiniteScrollModule` though - just had a brief look at its source.

Comment: @GünterZöchbauer yes I have only one module so already imported there, and its not like its not working, its just everytime time I have to scroll to top & then scroll down to make it work

Comment: @DheerajAgrawal  sometimes I also find that my scrolled function is not triggered. Then I have to do hard refresh on the page. Sometimes if my developer tools is open, it won't triggered it. I tried to observe the pattern many times but it is just random. Have you find the solution yet to this problem ? If yes then please do share with us.

Comment: @shahakshay94 not really, that's why I made my custom function which is working fine, it has some problems (have some hacks) but atleast its triggering every time

Comment: can you share that custom made function , if possible ?